# Register User - Added fields

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I am trying to register a user for my android app, currently it uses the Firebase authentication to register using a email and password. But I am trying to add a name and phone field to register with too.

```
Registration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // register name/phone/radiogroup


            final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            final String phone = phoneField.getText().toString();
            final String email = Email.getText().toString();
            final String password = Password.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this,
                        "Please enter your Name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this,
                        "Please enter your Phone Number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this,
                        "Please enter your Email Address...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this,
                        "Please enter a Password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Tradesman Registration");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we check your credentials...");
                loadingBar.show();

                Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, "Tradesman Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                            String name = nameField.getText().toString();
                            String phone= phoneField.getText().toString();

                            HashMap<String,String> user=new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("Name",name);
                            user.put("Phone",phone);


                            String user_id = Auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tradesman").child(user_id).child("Name");
                            current_user_db.setValue(email);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I've created the fields etc, I just am struggling with the part of putting the name and phone into the firebase database.

Currently it registers a user and sets the Name to the users email. I want to store the name and phone as children of the user ID(which they enter when registering), rather than just the email

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?  Is something not working the way you expect?  Please edit the question with more details, so we know what's wrong.

Comment: I am struggling with being able to add the extra fields when registering. I understand that currently it creates a user ID child and then a child 'Name' inside it with the email. I want to be able to register a user and add their name/phone as the children of the unique ID

Comment: You're going to have to explain *specifically* what you want the final result to be, and what your are doing now that isn't what you expect.  Please edit the question to add the details.

Comment: So I want the final result to be: I register a user using the authentication of email/password. This creates a unique ID for a user in the realtime database and stores the name and phone which the user enters as children. It currently stores the email the user enters as the Name, and I dont have a phone child field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the wrong value at `setValue`. Replace with this.

```
 DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tradesman").child(user_id);
 current_user_db.setValue(user);
```

Comment: Thankyou that makes sense, I knew the email in setValue was a problem but didn't know if I was correct using a Map

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a node under `/Users/Tradesman/$uid` with the name and phone number of the user, that'd look like this:

```
Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(TradesmanLoginActivity.this, "Tradesman Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();

            String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            String phone= phoneField.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String,String> user=new HashMap<>();
            user.put("Name",name);
            user.put("Phone",phone);

            String user_id = Auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users/Tradesman").child(user_id);
            current_user_db.setValue(user);
        }
    }
});
```

The biggest change is that you were only writing `email` in there, and the update above writes the entire map with both name and phone number.